# btn-danger effect is not applying using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I am working on a slider which is gets its values from a database, and the scenario is that if the "due date" of task is pending then it shows `btn-success` with status pending. If we finish the task then it shows `btn-warning` with status completed. If the "due date" passed then it still shows as `btn-success` with status pending. What I want to do is make it so if "due date" is passed then it shows `btn-danger` with status date passed.

screenshot https://ibb.co/HtMYnpZ and full code is here

> paste.ofcode.org/y6DWM6awBRjXvuYstv8uNH

code:

```
   if(response.task.status === 'completed') {
            $('.completed-task-table').stop().slideToggle();
            // $('#finishTaskForm').find('select[name=assignTo]').css('display', 'none');
            // $('#finishTaskForm').find('input[name=dueDate]').css('display', 'none');
            // $('#finishTaskForm').find('button').css('display', 'none');
            // utils.findAndAddFormAttribute(formAttrForDisabled);
        } else {
            $('.pending-task-table').stop().slideToggle();
            // $('#finishTaskForm').find('select[name=assignTo]').css('display', 'unset');
            // $('finishTaskForm').find('input[name=dueDate]').css('display', 'unset');
            // $('finishTaskForm').find('button').css('display', 'unset');
            utils.findAndRemoveFormAttribute(formAttributeForEnabled);
        }

function setTasksCarausel() {
  html = '<div class="carousel-inner no-padding">';
  let tasksCopy = utils.setSliders(Array.from(tasks));
  tasksCopy.map((tasks, index) => {
    html += `<div class="item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}">`;
    tasks.map(t => {
        html += `
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pending-task-btn" onclick="handleClickTaskItem('${t._id}')">
                <span href="" class="btn ${t.status === 'completed' ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-success'} btn-lg dashboard-icon" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                    <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">${t.type}</p>
                    <p style="padding-top: 12px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">${utils.convertDate(t.dueDate)}</p>
                    <p style="padding-top: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">( ${t.status } )</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        `;
    });
    html += `</div>`;
})
```

Comment: `<span href=""`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I feel as though I don't have enough information to completely answer your question, specifically what the format of t.dueDate is, I think something along these lines should work.

You should be able to just nest another inline if statement on this line.

```
"btn ${t.status === 'completed' ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-success'} btn-lg dashboard-icon"
```

Within this new if statement you should be comparing the current date to your t.dueDate.

```
"btn ${t.status === 'completed' ? 'btn-warning' : (new Date(t.dueDate) < new Date() ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-success')} btn-lg dashboard-icon"
```

NOTE: This depends though what the format of t.dueDate. The Date object in javascript expects certain formats but is actually quite flexable. You can find some examples of the excepted formats at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples

Comment: Exactly this thing i was required

Comment: now these are showing datewise and i wants to sort them same datewise with status like all btn-danger comes first and than btn-success and at end btn-warning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500585/how-to-sort-data-in-jquery