# How to sort data in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ejs

I'm working on a slider which is showing data from the backend. Using the "push" function it is showing slides in the slider according to date. But I need it to show these slides according to date & status.

Firstly show incomplete status (btn-danger), after it show pending status (btn-success), and then completed status (btn-warning).

screenshot of code https://ibb.co/5KJpdrh

full code:

> paste.ofcode.org/hmKSwTvaWrjTj3A6rWh464

code:

```
  function handleSubmit(command) {
    if(command === 'meeting') {

        let meetingFormValue = getMeetingFormValue('.create-meeting-form');
        httpService.post('http://localhost:3000/meeting/create', meetingFormValue)
            .then(response => {
                meetings.push(response);
                setMeetingCarausel();
            }).catch(ex => {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(ex);
            }) 
        // close the form
        $('.create-meeting-form').stop().slideToggle();
    }else if(command === 'task') {
        //attendees
        const taskFormValue = getTaskFormValue('#createTaskForm');
        httpService.post('http://localhost:3000/meeting/taskList/create', taskFormValue)
            .then(response => {
                tasks.push(response);
                setTasksCarausel();
            }).catch(ex => {
                console.log(ex);
            });

        // close the form
        $('.create-task-form').stop().slideToggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the data?

Comment: @ksav data is coming from db and showing in slides of slider https://ibb.co/5KJpdrh    it contains subject, date, status

Comment: Add the data to your question.

Comment: i added the screenshot of view and a full code

Comment: There's no data. Don't you want to sort the data?

Comment: data is already sorting in slides it is showing according to date i need to show it using date and status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208892/discussion-between-alpha-dev-and-ksav).

Comment: Why not having the data ordered by/ sorted from the backend/API? would be better.

Comment: i dont knw backend bcz thats in nodejs

Comment: @ksav  hi this function is working tasks.sort(function(a, b) { if(a.status !== b.status) { return a.status > b.status ? 1 :-1; } return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1; });

Comment: @ksav   its quite better ,,,,, the result is ibb.co/JF2yh3t but i need btn-danger 1st, then btn-success, then btn-warning,,, only to replace the position of btn-warning and btn-danger

Comment: @ksav can u suggest me some more thing

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

You should pass a compare function to have `sort()` use your criteria to sort your entries properly.

Comment: Now that I've pointed you in the right direction, try to read the docs first and learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: i have write this function by seeing it but its not working,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,tasks.push(response);
tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.status !== b.status) {
       return a.status > b.status ? 1 :-1;
   } 
    return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1;
});

Comment: tasks.push(response);
tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.status !== b.status) {
       return a.status > b.status ? 1 :-1;
   } 
    return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1;
});

Comment: hi this function is working  tasks.sort(function(a, b) { if(a.status !== b.status) { return a.status > b.status ? 1 :-1; } return a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1; });

Comment: its quite better ,,,,, the result is https://ibb.co/JF2yh3t

but i need btn-danger 1st, then btn-success, then btn-warning,,,

only to replace the position of btn-warning and btn-danger

Comment: can u suggest me some more thing